# Guru meditation error (LoadProhibited) on BLEDevice::Init with ESP32Cam

Tags: c++, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32, arduino-ide, platformio

I'm struggling with a Guru meditation error when I try to use BLEDevice::Init to get credential from a smartphone.

The begining of my code works but when I reach the Init part, I got this message :

```
Guru Meditation Error: Core  0 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled.

Core  0 register dump:
PC      : 0x40099c19  PS      : 0x00060330  A0      : 0x8009a8d2  A1      : 0x3ffdbf00  
A2      : 0xffffffff  A3      : 0xffffffff  A4      : 0x20000000  A5      : 0x00060f23  
A6      : 0x00060f20  A7      : 0x00000001  A8      : 0x00000003  A9      : 0x00000006  
A10     : 0x00000027  A11     : 0x0000111c  A12     : 0x00000013  A13     : 0x00000040  
A14     : 0xfffffffc  A15     : 0x00001ebc  SAR     : 0x00000007  EXCCAUSE: 0x0000001c  
EXCVADDR: 0x0000002b  LBEG    : 0x40092a70  LEND    : 0x40092a7b  LCOUNT  : 0x00000000
```

Here some sample of my code :

Definition of characteristics and other :

```cpp
BLEServer *pServer = NULL;
BLECharacteristic *pCharCredential = NULL;
BLECharacteristic *pCharMacAddr = NULL;
BLECharacteristic *pCharMacExtAddr = NULL;
BLECharacteristic *pCharBatLvl = NULL;

BLEService *pService = NULL;
BLEAdvertising *pAdvertising = NULL;
```

Callbacks :

```cpp
class MyServerCallbacks : public BLEServerCallbacks
{
  void onConnect(BLEServer *pServer)
  {
    BLEDevice::startAdvertising();
  };
};

class credentialCallback : public BLECharacteristicCallbacks
{
  void onWrite(BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic)
  {
    std::string value = pCharacteristic->getValue();
    // Store here SSID and password
    SSID = value.substr(0, value.find('|'));
    PWD = value.substr(value.find('|') + 1, value.size());
    state = STATE_SWITCH_MODE;
  }
};
```

And finally, the part where the exception occures :

```cpp
case STATE_BLE:
    BLEDevice::init(DEVICE_NAME); // <----- bug here
  

    pServer = BLEDevice::createServer();
    pServer->setCallbacks(new MyServerCallbacks());

    pService = pServer->createService(SERVICE_UUID);

    // Credential
    pCharCredential = pService->createCharacteristic(
        CREDENTIAL_UUID,
        BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ |
            BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE |
            BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_NOTIFY |
            BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_INDICATE);

    pCharCredential->setCallbacks(new credentialCallback());
    pCharCredential->addDescriptor(new BLE2902());

    // Main cam mac
    pCharMacAddr = pService->createCharacteristic(
        MAC_UUID,
        BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ |
            BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE |
            BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_NOTIFY |
            BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_INDICATE);

    pCharMacAddr->setValue(WiFi.macAddress().c_str());
    pCharMacAddr->addDescriptor(new BLE2902());

    // Secondary cam mac
    pCharMacExtAddr = pService->createCharacteristic(
        MAC_EXT_UUID,
        BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ |
            BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE |
            BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_NOTIFY |
            BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_INDICATE);

    pCharMacExtAddr->setValue(macExtCam.c_str());
    pCharMacExtAddr->addDescriptor(new BLE2902());

    // Battery level
    pCharBatLvl = pService->createCharacteristic(
        BAT_LVL_UUID,
        BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ |
            BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE |
            BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_NOTIFY |
            BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_INDICATE);

    char ctable[5];
    sprintf(ctable, "%d", batLvl);
    pCharBatLvl->setValue(ctable);
    pCharBatLvl->addDescriptor(new BLE2902());

    pService->start();

    pAdvertising = BLEDevice::getAdvertising();
    pAdvertising->addServiceUUID(SERVICE_UUID);
    pAdvertising->setScanResponse(false);
    pAdvertising->setMinPreferred(0x0); // set value to 0x00 to not advertise this parameter
    BLEDevice::startAdvertising();

    delay(10);
    state = STATE_IDLE;
    break;
```

One detailed that I have forget is that the problem just appeared few days ago, but it was working before (from October 2022 to 9 March 2023). This detail lead me to some debug try listed below.

I have been struggling since few day and I have tried many things, but always leads to the same error:

Hardware problems :

- It could be a problem of the ESP32 itself : I tried on 3 differents ESP32Cam
- Maybe the could be the programmer : I used 2 differents

Software problems :

- Libraries could be outdated : Update all libraries and boards
- I'm using PlatformIO : I tried on ArduinoIDE 2.0
- It could be an update of the library: installed previous version (on PlatformIO and ArduinoIDE)
- Try to use working code pushed on main branch : The problem appeared on my working code !!!!
- Commenting BLEDevice::Init : Don't crash but BLE not start ( as expected )
- Went deeper on BLEDevice::Init : problem seems to come from btStart() from esp32-hal-bt.h
- I reduced CPU clock frequency : Set it to default
- Bonus: Goat sacrifice didn't work

By watching error message: the problem seems to be a memory allocation problem, but I can't find why it occurs.

Can anyone help me ?

***Edit 1 :***
Add test on NULL pointer before using pServer, pService and all pCharacteristics, but change nothing :

```cpp
    pServer = BLEDevice::createServer();
    if (pServer == NULL)
    {
      Serial.println("Can't create server");
      break;
    }
```

Comment: Do yourself a favour and test each of the pointers you use for a value other than NULL before you use them and you will see that the problem practically solves itself.

Comment: I have add test on null pointer before using server, service and characteristics but it change nothing. But thank you for this precious advice wich will save me many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 3 weeks, I finnaly find why the error occurs.
It seems to be a problem of naming, I change the name provided in BLEDevice::Init then pushed the code, and it worked. I gave the old name and it worked again.